# How can I add and remove to / from a nested mongodb collection in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, node.js

I would like to add and remove "developers" in to the following mongodb collection. There can be many projects, each project can have many user stories, and each user story can have multiple developers working on it.

## Question:

What mongodb query can I use to add new developers to the "stories" collection, and what mongodb query can I use to remove developers from the "stories" collection?

**JSON for a Project:**

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("4ef0a2bac8c056bc26000002"),
   "chat": {
     "0": {
       "body": "Test",
       "sender": "brownj2",
       "sent": 1324404459137 
    } 
  },
   "clients": {
     "0": {
       "username": "b" 
    } 
  },
   "owner": "brownj2",
   "stories": {
     "0": {
       "_id": "U89Tq7X8BF2qaBfFzfE99lkb",
       "deadline": "10\/10\/2010",
       "description": "Example user story",
       "developers": {
         /* Developers go here */
       },
       "lane": "2",
       "roi": "0.38",
       "sp": "8",
       "title": "Test #2",
       "type": "story",
       "value": "3" 
    },
     "1": {
       "_id": "EdbzrnoZTh8LTFDNrUSBkVrd",
       "deadline": "10\/10\/2010",
       "description": ".....",
       "developers": {
         /* Developers go here */             
       },
       "lane": "0",
       "roi": "1.00",
       "sp": "4",
       "title": "Test #1",
       "type": "story",
       "value": "4" 
    } 
  },
   "team": {
     "0": {
       "username": "a" 
    } 
  },
   "title": "Example Project" 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it's a bit of a workaround, but it seems to work quite well. I'm doing some of the work on the server, rather than the database.

```
  projects.findOne({_id : projectId}, function(err, project)
  {
     for(var i = 0; i < project.stories.length; i++)
     {
       if(project.stories[i]._id == storyId)
       {
         var developers = project.stories[i].developers;
         var size = developers.length;

         var developers[size] = {username : username};

          projects.update( {"stories._id" : storyId},
                    {$set:
                      {
                        "stories.$.developers"  : developers
                      }
                    }, false, true);
       }
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have inconsistent design. Some of your collections are arrays, others are hashes.

I tend to use hashes more, but then I don't use plain 'numeric' indexes for items. For example:

```
"stories": {
    "0": {
        "_id": "U89Tq7X8BF2qaBfFzfE99lkb",
        "deadline": "10\/10\/2010",
```

would make more sense (to me) if it was written as

```
"stories": {
    "U89Tq7X8BF2qaBfFzfE99lkb": {
        "deadline": "10\/10\/2010",
```

The same goes for developers. I suppose they have IDs, right? So it should be

```
"developers": {
    dev1_id : {username : username1},
    dev2_id : {username : username2}
}
```

Now you can manage these objects with plain dotted `set`s

**Add new developer**

```
db.projects.update({_id: ObjectId("4ef0a2bac8c056bc26000002")},
                   {$set: {"stories.U89Tq7X8BF2qaBfFzfE99lkb.dev3_id" : username3})
```

**Pull a developer**

```
db.projects.update({_id: ObjectId("4ef0a2bac8c056bc26000002")},
                   {$unset: {"stories.U89Tq7X8BF2qaBfFzfE99lkb.dev1_id" : 1})
```

Comment: For some reason Rockmongo displays empty hashes with square brackets. In the JavaScript they're initiated using curly brackets. I'll modify the database and give this a try, thanks.

Comment: That's because it's written in PHP. And PHP can't tell apart empty array and empty hash (they are the same thing there, AFAIK)

Comment: I've had a look and there isn't a possibility of changing the database structure, as it would mean changing a large amount of queries and functions. Is there a viable answer to my above question without changing the db structure?

Comment: Please, revise your question first and make arrays arrays and hashes hashes (as they are in DB). Then we'll see.

Comment: I've updated the code in the question, I've revised MongoDB queries for the past few hours and can't find any method of working with doubly nested collections.

Comment: So, you still have black schema for developers? Go with my approach. It still works! `$set : {'stories.0.dev_id' : {username : dev_name}}`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6019/discussion-between-jack-and-sergei-tulentsev)